# How to prove this Generalisation of Napoleon Theorem?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

[Napoleon Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem) is classical theorem of Plane Geometry. Here we are giving it's Generalisation and wanted to see an easy method to prove it and also check whether it is old or new.

> Generalisation of Napoleon Theorem:

Let ABCD and CDEF be two Parallelogram as shown [in this figure.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq9erbp5wcjvrll/1638817627536.png?dl=0)
Let G be the apex of equilaterial triangle constructed on segment BF such that GBF is clockwise.

Similarly , H and I are apices of equilaterial triangle constructed on segment EC and DA such that HEC and IDA are clockwise.

Then Centroid of equilaterial triangle ∆GBF; ∆HEC and ∆IDA form Equilaterial triangle.

> Note:

1. When A=B , This reduce to Napoleon Theorem.
2. The construction also produced equilaterial triangle if clockwise replaced by counter clockwise.

---

We have also published the same results on [Euclid group.io](https://groups.io/g/euclid/topic/86859505#3009)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... It's a little easier to conceptualize the problem by starting with a $\triangle PQR$ and its translation $\triangle P'Q'R'$; from here, you've built equilateral triangles upon segments $\overline{PQ'}$, $\overline{QR'}$, $\overline{RP'}$, and discovered that the centers of these triangles form an equilateral triangle. (Congratulations!) ... Now, the standard proof of Napoleon's Theorem using complex numbers (or vectors) can be applied here with just a slight adjustment to account for the fact that $P' = P+T$, $Q' = Q+T$, $R'=R+T$ for some translation number/vector $T$.

Comment: Thanks!! sir Blue

Comment: The above mentioned GENERALISATION can also Generalised Van Abuels Theorem.                                                                   Let's take Quadrilateral PQRS and it's translation P'Q'R'S' and by making Square on PQ', QR', RS', SP' in same orientation and taking their Centroid as G1,G2,G3,G4 then we find that G1G3 is perpendicular to G2G4.                             See about Van Abuels Theorem here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Aubel's_theorem.                          ; We thanks to sir blue, if he don't tells about translation then we may not able to find this .

Comment: Now , we further try to Generalised this on N polygon by taking its translation .               Important Note : in above results when P =P' then it reduces to Van Abuels Theorem.